# How to filter a JavaScript object to show only the data I need

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have this json object- it's abbreviated, but it looks somewhat like the following

```
{
"q": [
    {
        "a": [],
        "asked_at": "2011-12-08T05:58:45.695958",
        "closed_at": null,
        "event": "/api/v1/event/2/",
        "id": "2",
        "is_open": true,
        "is_public": true,
        "question": "Testing the question entry point with curl",
        "updated_at": "2011-12-08T05:58:47.026834",
        "user": {
            "email": "test@t.com",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "profile": [],
            "username": "wout"
        }
    },
    {
        "a": [],
        "asked_at": "2011-12-08T05:59:39.941603",
        "closed_at": null,
        "event": "/api/v1/event/2/",
        "id": "3",
        "is_open": true,
        "is_public": true,
        "question": "Testing another question entry point with curl",
        "updated_at": "2011-12-08T05:59:43.388709",
        "user": {
            "email": "test@t.com",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "profile": [],
            "username": "wout"
        }
    }   
]
}
```

Where q is a question being asked, and every a would be an answer (not shown, no answers are given in this example).
How would I go about it, if I wanted to get only the one item with an id of '3' so that I would be left with a result of:

```
{
        "a": [],
        "asked_at": "2011-12-08T05:59:39.941603",
        "closed_at": null,
        "event": "/api/v1/event/2/",
        "id": "3",
        "is_open": true,
        "is_public": true,
        "question": "Here's a test entry point with curl",
        "updated_at": "2011-12-08T05:59:43.388709",
        "user": {
            "email": "test@t.com",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "profile": [],
            "username": "wout"
        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help- Thanks alot!
Marco

Comment: Have a look at http://jsonselect.org/ .

Comment: Just a pedantic point -- as people have taught me in the past, there's no such thing as a JSON object.  If it's a string, it's json, if it's an object, then it's an object.

Comment: Adam, thanks- that's a good thing to remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function can filter an array

```
var questionsWithId3 = $.grep(yourObj.q, function() { return this.id === "3"; });
```

This will return an array, so if you're sure there will only be one result, you can do:

```
var questionWithId3 = $.grep(yourObj.q, function() { return this.id === "3"; })[0];
```

Comment: I'll +1 you as soon as you change it to `this.id === "3"` since the number is stored as a string. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your JSON is parsed into JavaScript, here's a native JavaScript solution:

```
var obj = {
    q: [
       // ...
    ]
};

var result;

for( var i = 0; i < obj.q.length; ++i ) {
    if( obj.q[i] && obj.q[i].id === '3' ) {
        result = obj.q[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You love that pre-increment operator  ++i, don't you :)  I guess you're guaranteed to not have awful side effects that way.  +1 btw

Comment: @AdamRackis: Thanks. Yeah, it's pretty safe here either way, but outside of SO, I'd more likely grab the length, and do `while( len-- ) {...` unless there's a compelling reason to start at the beginning.

Comment: `while(len--)` - I **love** "neat" code like that that relies on nuances of the languages - 0 is falsy and -- happens after the loop's check.  So do people give you crap for stuff like that a lot like they do me?  ie, I've had people think that `return _foo ?? (_foo = getFoo());` isn't clear enough.  (in C#)  Pff

Comment: +1. I like `for (var i=0, len=obj.q.length; i<len; i++)` or `for (var i=obj.q.length; i--;)`

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yeah, people can get uptight about some of those things. I figure once you understand the language, they're as clear as anything else. They way I declare multiple variables would probably drive some people absolutely nuts.

Comment: `once you understand the language, they're as clear as anything else` exactly.  Maybe that argument would be harder to hold up with the crap you can do with C++, but C# and even JavaScript are pretty easy with a little effort.